# Simple SELECT procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this procedure in MySQL

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `AddNotificationOnPosts`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddNotificationOnPosts`(from_user INT(11),on_post_id INT(11),in_group_id INT(11))
BEGIN
    DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT count(notification_id) FROM notifications_posts 
    WHERE from_user = 1;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

and this table

```
notification_id from_user   on_post_id  in_group_id date
2   1   162 3   2012-07-11 12:01:08
3   19  163 1   2012-07-11 12:03:26
4   19  164 1   2012-08-10 17:42:36
5   1   165 3   2012-08-29 12:14:01
6   1   165 3   2012-08-29 12:14:29
```

when i execute:

```
SET @p0 =  '1';
SET @p1 =  '2';
SET @p2 =  '3';
CALL `AddNotificationOnPosts` ( @p0 , @p1 , @p2 );
```

it gives me:

```
count(notification_id)
5
```

why? because they are only 3 records of user_id 1

And also how do i make this procedure to:

1. Give an error or warning when values are not set
2. Get variables from the procedure, something like

   ```
   SELECT count(notification_id) FROM notifications_posts 
   WHERE from_user = @from_user;
   ```

Comment: Note that you've hard coded your filter `WHERE from_user = 1` - did you mean to use the `from_user` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use different names for arguments:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddNotificationOnPosts
(arg_from_user INT(11),arg_on_post_id INT(11),arg_in_group_id INT(11))
BEGIN
    DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;

    IF(arg_from_user  IS NULL OR arg_from_user = '')
    THEN 
        SELECT "Error:Invalid argument for userID" AS error_code;
    ELSE
        SELECT count(notification_id) 
        INTO num_rows
        FROM notifications_posts 
        WHERE from_user = arg_from_user;
    END IF;

    SELECT num_rows;
END $$
```

Comment: so the solution is to rename the vars?

Comment: and "error_code" is reserved keyword? or is the same thing as "SELECT column as "cool name" ... ?? (ALIAS)

Comment: no it's just an alias and not a reserved word, you can give any alias of your own choice.

Comment: maybe is better to just return 0 as an error or as 0 rows, thank you very much, i'm learning procedures now :)

Comment: and is there a method to have same names at args? like name = this.name (java)

Comment: no MySQL is not object oriented database so doesn't support `this.`

Comment: and one more thing please, how do fetch the response of the   `INSERT INTO notifications_posts(from_user,on_post_id,in_group_id) VALUES(arg_from_user,arg_on_post_id,arg_in_group_id);` ?? In PHP i would fetch the $result of the $query, but how do i do the same here?

Comment: using `ROW_COUNT()` function after your `INSERT` query http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count

Comment: and if ROW_COUNT() > 0 THEN the INSERT WAS SUCCESSFULLY , right?